# How to get google-service.json file and google app id for integrating Airpush ads on android

Tags: android, json, google-app-engine

I want to integrate Airpush ads on my android app. But the problem occurs on the second step of their [official documentation](http://docs.airpush.com/index.php/Universal_SDK_8.13). I have never used google play service in any of my app.So I don't know how to do this. I see my logcat and it was saying

> Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services. Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin

**I followed this [instruction](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cntpkg=com.google.samples.quickstart.signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20with%20Try%20Sign-In) and this [instruction](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start?hl=en) also. But I am not understanding this. Because in the first instruction, after creating app Google is saying me to choose service. But here is my problem that I don't know which service is required for integrating Airpush.**

So, I need help. I don't know how to get my google app id and get the json file. Please give me step by step instructions for this.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The first, go to :

https://console.cloud.google.com/home

then select your google project. Go to Dashboard than you can see your **project id** and **project number**

The second, you can go to this page to get your **google-services.json** file:

https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=gcm&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fandroid%2Fclient&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20GCM%20Support&%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue

Comment: But when I am going to get the json file - after completing first step they are saying me to choose a service. I don't know what service I need to use for integrating Airpush ads

Comment: just choose android, man. You're working with android and airpush just support for it :D

Comment: But there is no option named Android. There are Google Sing-In, Cloud Messaging, Analytics, App Invites and AdMob. Now which will I select for integrating Airpush?

Comment: yes, plz choose admob. It doesn't have android option. sorry for this

Comment: But why AdMob? I am not going to integrate AdMob! Any specific reason?